# How do we prove that a specific kernel is positive definite (case of logarithm)?

Tags: functional-analysis, positive-definite

I have a problem proving that some specific kernels are positive definite. In general, I can find the answer quickly enough but here I have a specific case involving a logartihm :

$K:\mathbb{R}_+\times\mathbb{R}_+$ with $K(x,y)=\log(1+xy)$
I've tried a lot of different things (using series, writing it as an integral), but it seems to be impossible to prove it.

Thanks for helping me